# JavaFX BorderPane

Tags: javafx, borderpane

i'm trying to set on top of a borderpane an fxml hbox, the borderpane is inside another borderpane that contains all.
The containers are in this form: 
Stage-> PincipalBorderPane -> Vbox(Center of MainMenuBorderPane)-> ContentBorderPane(in bottom of Vbox).
Also in the left of my PrincipalBorderPane, I have a sidebar menu that contains buttons, I want to set on the top of ContentBorderPane an fxml document that will be like an small menu to show buttons that would set on the bottom of ContentMenu different panes. The problem is that I don't know how to set an fxml to a borderpane that is inside another borderpane.

```
public class MenuContentController implements Initializable {

private boolean flag = true;
private boolean flagsc = true;

@FXML
private JFXButton Minbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton Maxbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton Closebtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton Sidebarbtn;

@FXML
private JFXTextField Searchtxt;

@FXML
private JFXButton Ingressbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton Egressbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton Statusbtn;

@FXML
private BorderPane ContentTools;

@FXML
private void open_sidebar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    BorderPane border_pane = (BorderPane) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getRoot();
    if (flag) {
        //Revisar animación más adelante
        Parent sidebar = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/app/fxml/Sidebar.fxml"));
        sidebar.translateXProperty();
        //
        border_pane.setLeft(sidebar);
        //
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(sidebar.translateXProperty(),0,Interpolator.EASE_IN);
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), kv);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        timeline.play();
        flag = false;
    } else {
        border_pane.setLeft(null);
        flag = true;
    }

}
**@FXML
public void open_admintools_priv(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    ContentTools = new BorderPane();
    BorderPane bp = (BorderPane) ContentTools;
  if (flagsc) {
       Parent admintools = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/app/fxml/AdminTools.fxml")); 
       bp.setTop(admintools);
       flagsc=false;
    } else {
       ContentTools.setTop(null);
       flagsc = true;
    }
    System.out.println(flagsc);**
}
```

The method open_admintools_priv should to set visible on top of ContentTools(ContentBorderpane) the Admintools.fxml by pressing a button in another fxml(sidebar.fxml) that I set on the left of my PrincipalBorderPane with the method open_sidebar, that I call creating a new controller of MenuContentController in the SidebarController:

```
public class SidebarController implements Initializable {
private boolean flagsc = true;
@FXML
private JFXButton condominiobtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton adminbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton finanzasbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton reportesbtn;

@FXML
private JFXButton confbtn;
@FXML
private void open_admintools(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
  MenuContentController aux = new MenuContentController();
  aux.open_admintools_priv(event);

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

Another problem is that by this way, at the moment I create a MenuContentController, the variable flag is always on true, this variable I use it to set the fxml in borderpane when flag is true, or quit it when flag is false. I don't know if creating an instance of a controller is the way to acces to the objects of that fxml, thanks for your time.

[image: Principal Borderpane, clicking Sidebar set on left the Sidebar.fxml IMAGE]

[image: Graphic explanation IMAGE]

Comment: The newly created `BorderPane` is never added to the scene. Are you sure you need to create a new one and assign it to a `@FXML` annotated field instead of using the field injected by `FXMLLoader`? If this isn't working without creating a new `BorderPane`, the injection of the node isn't working. (Note: In such a case it's never a good idea to use java code to set the field to cover up the NPE, since this is simply hiding the symptoms, not fixing the issue.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't meet your expectations.
And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.